# How many people died in the mainline series of Goosebumps?

Tags: books, goosebumps, fear-street

*Goosebumps* is known to be substantially tempered compared to other horror series and anthologies, even ones written by R.L. Stine himself. (Such as *Fear Street*). The gore is minimal, which is probably connected to the primary audience of the books, older children and pre-teens.

But there seems to have been some deaths and implied deaths with cliffhanger endings. Does anyone know how many deaths occurred in the *main* series (1992-1997)? Interested in the first 62 books, not really any of the spinoffs such as *Give Yourself Goosebumps* (1995-2000) or *Goosebumps 2000* (1998-2000), but you can include counts for those separately if you wish.

A count for the four seasons of the series would be interesting too.

In contrast, how many deaths occur in *Fear Street* (the original 51 books)? I'd be happy to know the count for *Ghosts of Fear Street* or *Fear Street Sagas* as well.

Comment: Do you speak about the books or the series, or both? The Goosebump books are around 100 and the Fear Street ones around 160...

Comment: To clearify: There are around 100 Goosebump books and around 160 of Fear Street (around 50 of the main storyline)